# KeyCloak and SAML - flow does not return to SP

Tags: keycloak

This is my scenario:

I need to provide SAML authentication/authorization flow to a web app. I have an SP developed in Spring and two IdP with Keycloak, let's call them IdP1 and IdP2.

The user is already registered in IdP1.

SP requires identification from IdP1, but IdP1 **must** delegate the identification to IdP2 via Identity Providers. Now IdP2, in order to register the user, must have the same userId/email that the user is registered in IdP1, so IdP2 delegates the identification to IdP1 (also via Identity Providers) and get the required information. Then, the IdP2 performs additional tasks (let's say that IdP1 can't do) and returns the flow to IdP1. And finally, IdP1 callbacks to the SP web with the user identified.

I've achieved all the steps but the last one. When the IdP2 returns the authentication flow to IdP1, the flow stops there showing the "You are already login in" message.

My questions are:

- Is there any configuration that I can modify to automatically redirect from IdP1 to SP in the last step?
- Is there any other way to pass the userId/email from the IdP1 to IdP2?
- Could this flow even work?

Thanks in advance!